# pkgdown htmlwidget - Examples

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have tried pkgdown for many htmlwidgets but no example work. They all return the [same error](https://johncoene.github.io/echarts4r/reference/e_bar.html):

```
USArrests %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    State = row.names(.),
    Rape = -Rape
  ) %>%
  e_charts(State) %>%
  e_bar(Murder) %>%
  e_bar(Rape, name = "Sick basterd", x.index = 1) # second y axis
#> Error in yaml.load(readLines(con), error.label = error.label, ...): argument "error.label" is missing, with no default
```

- Reverting `yaml` package version did not help.
- Upgrading to pandoc `2.1.3` did not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly htmlwidgets are not supported in `pkgdown` at the time of writing this, see issues [617](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/617) and [343](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/pull/343).